# Alt+Left Click , how to remove shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, blender

I have Ubuntu and GNOME 3 and when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> it grabs the current window. How do I stop this from happening, as I need this shortcut in Blender which I update often so changing it inside Blender is not logical.

Answer (score 6):

In your **Compiz Config Settings Manager** click on "Move Window" plugin. Click on the very first mouse shortcut (it should be `<ALT>Button1`) and Disable it.

Comment: I have tried this but every time it it dont work, if i reopen Compiz Config Settings Manager its reverted back to alt+button1

Comment: What if you try to delete the value in gconf-editor? Key is stored in /apps/compiz-1/plugins/move/screen0/options

Comment: never mind i fixed in the thge keyboard layout app, changed the setting under the layouts tab to the second option and it seems to have fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

If CompizConfig doesnt work for you, try this:

**Fix using dconf Editor**

Install dconf Editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Search for dconf Editor in dash and run it, then search for `mouse-button-modifier` and change the key from `<Alt>` to `<Super>` or anything else. That worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Xubuntu instead. I struggled a bunch with this, and was pointed toward Xubuntu because its interface steals from apps less, and is more customizable.

Comment: The question is about GNOME. An answer about switching desktop environments is an bit out of scope I think.